# create valid json object in python

Tags: python, json

Each line is valid JSON, but I need the file as a whole to be valid JSON.

I have some data which is aggregated from a web service and dumped to a file, so it's JSON-eaque, but not valid JSON, so it can't be processed in the simple and intuitive way that JSON files can - *thereby consituting a major pain in the neck*, it looks (more or less) like this:

```
{"record":"value0","block":"0x79"} 
{"record":"value1","block":"0x80"}
```

I've been trying to reinterpret it as valid JSON, my latest attempt looks like this:

```
with open('toy.json') as inpt:
    lines = []
    for line in inpt:
        if line.startswith('{'):  # block starts
            lines.append(line)
```

However, as you can likely deduce by the fact that I'm posing this question- that doesn't work- any ideas about how I might tackle this problem?

**EDIT:**

Tried this:

```
with open('toy_two.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    lines = [json.loads(line) for line in inpt] 

print(lines['record'])
```

but got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json-ifier.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(lines['record'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Ideally I'd like to interact with it as I can with normal JSON, i.e. `data['value']`

**EDIT II**

```
with open('transactions000000000029.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    lines = [json.loads(line) for line in inpt]

    for line in lines: 
        records = [item['hash'] for item in lines]
    for item in records: 
        print item
```

Comment: Is each line valid JSON? eg: does `lines = [json.loads(line) for line in inpt]` do the job?

Comment: `lines.append(json.loads(line))`?

Comment: yes but I don't want to process each line- I want to process the file as a whole- the real one has millions of records

Comment: In what way does `[json.loads(line) for line in inpt]` not constitute "processing the file as a whole" ?

Comment: @ChrisMartin when I gave it a shot I got this `print(lines['record']) TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: I'm quite confused now. If this file *were* valid JSON, it would be a list, right? What type do you want to interpret it as?

Comment: I want it to go from JSON-esque to valid JSON

Comment: I doubt you would want it to be JSON; it would consume gigabytes of RAM and had to be processed all at once, if some kind of iterative JSON module was not used...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like NDJSON that I've been working with recently. The specification is [here](http://ndjson.org/) and I'm not sure of its usefulness. Does the following work?

```
with open('the file.json', 'rb') as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()
    data = [json.loads(item.replace('\n', '')) for item in data]
```

This should give you a list of dictionaries.

Comment: when I tried it out just now I got this error `print(data['record'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`, how can I verify that this works?

Comment: Because this parses the file and gives you a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary.

Comment: but I want to interact with it like I can with json, in normal json I can call things like `data['record']` you know what I mean?

Comment: @s.matthew.english You can still interact with it like you would normally. It's perfectly fine for a JSON response to contain lists. I really don't get the NDJSON format but it now exists, so it's a list of dicts. `data[0]['record']` should give you a result, and you should be able to iterate through the list to get the other results.

Comment: damn- I'm sorry it was exactly the `data[0]['record']`- thank you for your great help!~ :)

Comment: man- how can I iterate over all these reocrds? `items()` isn't working

Comment: @s.matthew.english it's still a list, so `items()` is out. `records = [item['record'] for item in data]` should do it? I guess the point of the format is that every line is valid json, but the file as a whole is not. I find this a bit uncomfortable too, but you do just have a list of dictionaries so if you know how to iterate through lists and grab things by key, it's not that bad.

Comment: so this isn't it `    for line in lines: 
        records = [item['record'] for item in lines]
        print(records)` but... do you have some idea?

Comment: No, drop `for line in lines:`. Right under the code I posted, just do `records = [item['record'] for item in data]`. There's no point in `print` in that loop because I gave you a list comprehension. After the list comp, you could do `for item in records: print item` if you choose.

Comment: so, I made **EDIT II** in the OP, popped out the printing part- it works for the toy file, but for the million records file- it just never finishes- maybe it's breaking or... do you have some idea?

Comment: so yeah- it works on the format- but maybe it's just- excruciatingly slow- do you hve some idea on how to pump up the execution speed?

Comment: @s.matthew.english if you're talking about million of lines then maybe this format comes into its own. You can perhaps read it in chunks, which is tough for a flat json file.

Comment: @s.matthew.english get rid of `print` as that's massively expensive. Also, `for line in lines: ` makes no sense since you're working on list anyway. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

Each line looks like a valid JSON document.

That's "JSON Lines" format (http://jsonlines.org/)

Try to process each line independantly (`json.loads(line)`) or use a specialized library (https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
def process(oneline):
    # do what you want with each line
    print(oneline['record'])

with open('toy_two.json', 'rb') as inpt:
    for line in inpt:
        process(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: I'd like to process the file as a whole- as the real one has millions of records

Comment: So ? You can just iterate on each line of the input file as you do in your code, and apply json.loads(line) inside the 'for' loop.

Comment: sounds expensive, I want to do it cheap and fast

Comment: If you store all parsed lines in a global list, yes this is going to be expensive in RAM. If you process each line independantly, then you only use a bit of memory for the current line. That's "flow based programming".

Comment: ok cool- it was just the `data[0]['record']` issue- anyway- thank you for these great insights!