# Reading a stacked JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, import

I have a big JSONS file (4,5 GB) that I cannot open with Python all at once. The file consist of a few million lines which are all in JSON format. Each line is a seperate JSON file in brackets so the format of the file is:

```
{JSON}
{JSON}
{JSON}
...
```

I would like to be able to read the file line by line or a like the 200 first lines all at once but I can't figure out how to do this.
Would it be possible to read the file line by line and then put the desired parts of the individual JSONs in a dataframe? Or would the dataframe be too big to handle too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256301/create-valid-json-object-in-python/46256388#46256388) for reading jsonlines. You can do something similar for 200 lines at a time.

Comment: "cannot open with Python all at once", what makes you write that, what have you tried?

Comment: Well my computer cannot handle such big files..

Comment: If you would like people to help you, it would be good if you could provide as detailed information as possible, on what commands/modules you have already tried. Simply saying "Well my computer cannot handle such big files.."/"cannot open with Python all at once" doesn't shed any light on the issue and if you read the file line-by-line, I am almost certain that your computer can handle the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can read one line from file using [file.readline()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm) method.

Desired parts of JSON could be stored in memory, but make sure, to limit the size and then flush data to another file or database

Answer (score 0):

If you open a file with the usual python way of reading files, you do read it line by line. So you can do this

```
with open('big.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        #select stuff
```