# opening JSON file in R

Tags: r, json

I was trying to open a JSON file using fromJSON or read_json from jsonlite package, but it does not work and I keep receiving the following message:

My code is:

```
fromJSON("Kickstarter_2015-06-12.json", flatten=TRUE)


> Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
          rency_trailing_code": true}} {"id" : 87222572, "robot_id" : 
                     (right here) ------^
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a comma between the JSON objects. Or, you have what is known as NDJSON. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50430510/5977215

Comment: The error code is pointing you to something being wrong in the section starting with the `"id" = 87222572` - I'd have an eyeball around there in a text editor if possible. Is this the file by the way - https://webrobots.io/kickstarter-datasets/ ?

Comment: Hello, yes exactly it is from webrobots' Kickstarter tracker. seems like I cannot open their JSON files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gzf <- system.file("extdata", "testgz.json.gz", package="ndjson")
nrow(stream_in(gzf))
```

Or

```
mydata <- stream_in(file(tmp))
nrow(mydata)

# stream over HTTP
diamonds2 <- stream_in(url("http://jeroen.github.io/data/diamonds.json"))
```

Some great examples

[Streaming JSON Input/Output](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.5/topics/stream_in%2C%20stream_out)

[Stream In & Flatten An Ndjson File Into A Tbl_dt](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ndjson/versions/0.6.0/topics/stream_in)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:
ndjson::stream_in()