# How to read a newline delimited JSON file from R?

Tags: python, r, jsonlite

I have a newline delimited (i.e., each JSON object is confined to 1 line in the file):

```
{"name": "json1"}
{"name": "json2"}
{"name": "json3"}
```

In Python I can easily read it as follows (I must use the encoding `encoding='cp850'` to read my real data):

```
import json

objs = []
with open("testfile.json", encoding='cp850') as f:
    for line in f:
        objs.append(json.loads(line))
```

How can I do a similar trick in R?

At the end I want to get a data.frame:

```
library("jsonlite")
library("data.table")

d <- fromJSON("testfile.json", flatten=FALSE)
df <- as.data.frame(d)
```

Comment: Can you show the dput of `d`

Comment: Try with `read_json` or `stream_in`

Comment: I cannot show `d` because `fromJSON` fails with the following error: `Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       testfile.json
                     (right here) ------^`

Comment: I would read with `read_json` and see if it works (`d <- read_json('testfile.json')`

Comment: _I have a newline delimited (i.e., each JSON object is confined to 1 line in the file)_ Why? Do you have any way of changing that?

Comment: Most of IOT messages are received in new line jsons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `stream_in` from `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
out <- stream_in(file('testfile.json'))
out
#    name
#1 json1
#2 json2
#3 json3

str(out)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
#$ name: chr  "json1" "json2" "json3"
```

Comment: Hi @akrun : the stream_in() works on unboxed json. Is there a way to make it work on boxed single line json?

Comment: @LazarusThurston can you please post as a new question

Comment: Sure. Taking it out as a new question.

Comment: It's working for now :P. Will postpone posting the question for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can read & process the data to a proper format and then parse the JSON

```r
jsonlite::fromJSON(sprintf('[%s]', paste(readLines('text.json', warn = FALSE), 
                                         collapse = ',')))

#    name
# 1 json1
# 2 json2
# 3 json3
```

(you can use one of the *many* alternatives as JSON package e.g.

- `jsonlite` a more `R`-like package as it will mainly work with data frames
- `RJSONIO` a more `Python`-ic package working mainly with lists

or yet another one)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to read in newline json is probably `stream_in` from `ndjson`. It uses underlying `C++` libraries (although I think it is still single threaded). Still, I find it much faster than (the still very good) `jsonlite` library. As a bonus, the `json` is flattened by default.

```
library(ndjson)
out<- ndjson::stream_in(path='./testfile.json')
```