# Read json files in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read a file which has the contents in the below format:

```
{"op":"mcm","clk":"6394474220","pt":1523095339090,"mc":[{"id":"1.141299528","rc":[{"atb":[[10,5.56]],"id":30246}],"con":true,"img":false}]}
{"op":"mcm","clk":"6394627886","pt":1523096762118,"mc":[{"id":"1.141299528","rc":[{"atb":[[10.5,20.78]],"id":30246}],"con":true,"img":false}]}
{"op":"mcm","clk":"6394647672","pt":1523096790720,"mc":[{"id":"1.141299528","rc":[{"atb":[[10,22.23]],"id":30246}],"con":true,"img":false}]}
```

I am trying to read it as json but it seems these are multiple jsons in one file.
When I trying to read this json file using:

```
connection_file = open(filepath, 'r')
conn_string = json.load(connection_file)
```

It gives an error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1

Please let me know how to read such files.

Comment: Take your JSON and paste it into https://jsonlint.com/ and click "Validate json". It will tell you whether your JSON is valid

Comment: It seems you have a file where each line is a JSON string, but the file as a whole is not valid JSON.

Comment: Following on from @Mike's observation that means you should loop over the file line by line and use `json.loads` on each line instead of `json.load` for the entire lot.

Comment: It says:
Error: Parse error on line 16:
... "img": false }]} { "op": "mcm", "cl
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

But how to fix this?

Comment: For the sake of completion: you need to make sure / agree with whoever produces this JSON that the delimiter between JSON "documents" in the input will be a new line. That is, that new lines are not allowed within a single JSON document as they usually would be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python)

Comment: (While it is possible to hypothetically load a stream of JSON documents that are prettyprinted, most parsing libraries aren't built to handle that and won't make your life easier.)

Comment: @MikeScotty - nice catch, I've never heard of raw_decode being able to do that, might come in handy if my job search goes well

Comment: @millimoose it looks to follow the [jsonlines](http://jsonlines.org/) specification (or [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/)). I have seen it used a few times for repeatable output formats e.g. timed lines in log files.

Comment: @roganjosh I mean… it’s nice that it has a name, great that it has a spec, but there seems to be a lack when it comes to general purpose parsing libraries

Answer (score 1):

Your file isn't a valid `json` file. Each line is a `json` but they are delimited by newlines. You can use this to get them all as a list:

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    jsons = list(map(json.loads, f))
# jsons is now a list of all jsons in your file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like file is not a proper json file, but contains json data in each line. So read the file line by line and convert it to json

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('tmp.txt') as f:
...     json_list = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
... 
>>> json_list
[{'op': 'mcm', 'clk': '6394474220', 'pt': 1523095339090, 'mc': [{'id': '1.141299528', 'rc': [{'atb': [[10, 5.56]], 'id': 30246}], 'con': True, 'img': False}]}, {'op': 'mcm', 'clk': '6394627886', 'pt': 1523096762118, 'mc': [{'id': '1.141299528', 'rc': [{'atb': [[10.5, 20.78]], 'id': 30246}], 'con': True, 'img': False}]}, {'op': 'mcm', 'clk': '6394647672', 'pt': 1523096790720, 'mc': [{'id': '1.141299528', 'rc': [{'atb': [[10, 22.23]], 'id': 30246}], 'con': True, 'img': False}]}]
```