# How to split json payload and trigger POST request

Tags: python-3.x

Follwing is the Json :
[
  {
    "fcId": 621,
    "user": null,
    "fcName": "test1",
    "fcVNFs": [
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 40
      },
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 1
      },
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 3
      },
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 60
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "fcId": 682,
    "user": null,
    "fcName": "test2",
    "fcVNFs": [
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 40
      },
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 2
      },
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "fcId": 701,
    "user": null,
    "fcName": "test3",
    "fcVNFs": [
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 20
      },
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 3
      },
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 2
      },
      {
        "vnfFunctionId": 60
      }
    ]
  }
]

here I have to split the json removing "fcId" and corresponding value and trigger POST request.How to do that?Please help..

Comment: That's not legal JSON. Is this a json list `[{}, {}, {}]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python)