# Tweets streamed using tweepy, reading json file in python

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I streamed tweets using the following code

```
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('brasil.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True
```

Now I  have a json file (brasil.json). I want to open it on python to do sentiment analysis but I can't find a way. I managed to open the first tweet using this:

```
with open('brasil.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweets.append(json.loads(line))
```

but it doesn't read all the other tweets. Any idea?

Comment: Your code works when I test it. What is the length of your final `tweets` list? I ran your `CustomStreamListener` for about a minute and got 1,813 tweets, then ran your code to read the saved `json` and `tweets` list is 1,813 long. So, I can't reproduce reading only one tweet, it reads all tweets. Check the length of your `tweets` list again?

Comment: I also have around 2000 tweets (if I open it with excel). But in python I get this error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Comment: It seems like there is missing data (the "Expecting value") or the data written is inconsistent. What does `"line 2 column 1 (char 1)"` look like when you load the file in in Excel? (line 2, column 1)

Comment: When I open in excel I have all the tweets in the odd number if rows. The even numbers are blank

Comment: ok there are 2 easy fixes: you can either 1) read only the odd number rows (`for n, line in enumerate(f):`), or 2) use `try / except` with `except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: pass`. Try whichever one you prefer and see if it works. Or, if you'd prefer I could put them in an answer, as it's difficult to format code in comments

Comment: Please, i would appreciate that

Comment: No sample data was provided but I guess you have a JSON stream, so [How to extract multiple JSON objects from one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/how-to-extract-multiple-json-objects-from-one-file) might help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments: after examining the contents of the `json` data-file, all the tweets are in the odd number if rows. The even numbers are blank.

This caused a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`.

There are two ways to handle this error, either read only the odd rows or use exception-handling.

using odd rows:

```
with open('brasil.json') as f:
    for n, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if n % 2 == 1: # this line is in an odd-numbered row
            tweets.append(json.loads(line))
```

exception-handling:

```
with open('brasil.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            tweets.append(json.loads(line))
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            pass # skip this line
```

try and see which one works best.

Comment: The first option keeps showing the same error, and the second gives me this error: 'NameError: name 'f' is not defined'

Comment: the error in the first option may be due to how python indexes lines starting from `0`, but excel starts with `1`. The second is the same `f` variable used in your original code from the question. Please check the updated code.

Comment: Oh maybe you should know, the first part of the code is what I used to get the tweets. Now I am working on a new script to open the brasil.json file. I dont know if this affects anything

Comment: Yes, thanks and good point... I did use both parts of your code to reproduce the issue. We could try to fix the first part to not write data to json if data is empty .... But my answer only fixes the script to open the `'brasil.json'` file.

Comment: Please try the new code in the answer? I just now fixed it.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem! Thankss. I used the first option btw