# How to read in file with dict objects not separated by commas into dataframe and is this data JSON-LD format?

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-ld

I have a JSON file (`file1.json`) that looks this:

```
{"key":"value","key":"value"}
{"key":"value","key":"value"}
```

I cant read in this file with `pd.read_json('filepath/file1.json')` I get error:

`ValueError: Expected object or value`

I tried opening the file and reading in the `with open` like so:

```
with open('~/filepath/file1.json') as f:
    json_data = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(f.read()),encodings='utf-8-sig')
```

But I get error:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

However, when I read remove all rows except the top 2 from the file and add a comma like so:

```
{"key":"value","key":"value"},
{"key":"value","key":"value"}
```

I can read in the file as is with `pd.read_json()`.

How can I read in the file with non comma separated file dict objects per line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must use json.JSONDecoder()

Check this:

[complex json file to csv in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73012261/complex-json-file-to-csv-in-python/73012864#73012864)

and this:

[how to analyze json objects that are NOT separated by comma (preferably in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663739/how-to-analyze-json-objects-that-are-not-separated-by-comma-preferably-in-pytho)

You have to read the json, put the dicts in list and then use pd.json_normalize()