# Not able to parse JSON (which is not nested JSON) object coming from socket in python

Tags: python, json, sockets

New in python, I am reading JSON object from the server, size of JSON object is not fix. I am getting data from the server as per the buffer size given in socket.recv(1024). How to check that JSON object from server-socket received is full/complete, Because while parsing that JSON I am getting an error.
Please note that my JSON object is not nested.

**** Sample code ****

```
def get_data():
    s = socket.socket()
    host = 'IP_Address'
    port = 'Port_Number'

    # connection to hostname on the port.
    s.connect((host, port))
    msg=''
    while(True):        
        msg = s.recv(1024)
        print(msg.decode('ascii'))   
        jsonObject=json.loads(msg.decode('ascii'))     

    s.close()
```

Below is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "d:/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/Python_Test.py", line 26, in <module>
    get_data()

  File "d:/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/Python_Test.py", line 20, in get_data
    temp=json.loads(msg.decode('ascii'))

  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxx\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxx\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 777)
```

Comment: Please show us what is `msg` in your code (print it before the line that has error)

Comment: I think `msg` has more than one JSON objects.

Comment: You print what you have received. Could you share it here, so that we can better understand what happens?

Comment: @SergeBallesta you are right. I delete that comment :) May be the problem is because of recieving only 1024 bytes in every loop and the size of the json is bigger than that

Comment: @shotgunner below is the message.{"divice_id":"37843","slot":"2019-03-13 11:49:58.255","1":"237.51","2":"240.79","3":"241.48","4":"10.28","62":"383.0"}
{"divice_id":"33295","slot":"2019-03-13 11:49:58.33","1":"238.88","2":"240.71","3":"241.05","4":"165.9","5":"187.63","6":"162.47","7":"3630

Comment: Yes size of my Json object is bigger and also getting more than one json object in one msg. client is getting msg as per the buffer size.

Comment: @shotgunner so can you tell me please how can I loop the `recv` to recive complete JsonObject and one message at a time

Comment: @Amit Add this to the question you ask to help others too.

Comment: @Amit is your json not nested ? like this : `{"device_id": {"another_item": 2}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You recieve 1024 bytes in every loop and if your json object is bigger than that you have to handle **uncompleted** json string.
 Also you may have two json object in 1024 bytes or even more. you can change your code to below code

```
def get_data():
    s = socket.socket()
    host = 'IP_Address'
    port = 'Port_Number'
    s.connect((host, port))
    msg=''
    while True:        
        r = s.recv(1024)
        msg += r.decode('ascii')
        while True:
            start = msg.find("{")
            end = msg.find("}") 
            if start==-1 or end==-1:   # if can not find both { and } in string  
                break
            jsonObject=json.loads(msg[start:end+1])  # only read { ... } and not another uncompleted data
            #  do whatever you want with jsonObject here
            msg = msg[end+1:]
    s.close()
```

**NOTE :  this code work correct only if you have not any nested json in your data** (like this: `{"device_id": {"another_json": "something"}}`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I tried to execute your code, I got below error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment. So where should I declare that r inside while loop or outside while loop

Comment: And when I declare that r='' below msg='' and above while loop I got below error  r += s.recv(1024) TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: @Amit this was a type in `r += ` I fix the code check it now

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the required output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till the complete json is received and then parse it, something like this should work:

```
msg = ''
while(True):        
    response = s.recv(1024)
    if not response:
        break
    msg += response
jsonObject=json.loads(msg.decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, what if in the case where I received two JSON obj in the same msg.

Comment: @Amit in that case `json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode` is the right way. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50384432/380829