# split a string of multiple lists to multiple json objects

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a string of multiple lists, each list contains multiple json objects

```
'[{"user": "use1", "fullname": "full1"}][{"user": "use2", "fullname": "full2"}, {"user": "use3", "fullname": "full3"}][{"user": "use4", "fullname": "full4"}]'
```

the expected result should be

```
[{"user": "use1", "fullname": "full1"},{"user": "use2", "fullname": "full2"},{"user": "use3", "fullname": "full3"},{"user": "use4", "fullname": "full4"}]
```

How can I get the json objects into one list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python)

Comment: the answers there did not help y problem

Comment: provide proper example and expected output.

Comment: done, you can check it out

Comment: It seems there are some commas missing in your output. Also, is it intentionally that the parts with "use2" and "use3" are inside one square-bracket-block in your input? If i see it right, this may change a lot...

Comment: for the output i forgot the commas but yes, user2 and 3 are in a separate list

Answer (score 0):

```py
            data = data.split('[')[1:]

            data=[line[:-1] for line in data]

            elts = []
            for i in range(len(data)):
                try:
                    elt = json.loads(data[i], encoding='utf-8')
                    elts.append(elt)
                except Exception as e:
                    line= '[' + data[i] + ']'
                    elt = json.loads(line, encoding='utf-8')
                    elts.extend(elt)
```