# Getting JSON file into dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am trying to convert a JSON file into python dict. but I failed.

Here is my JSON file:

`me.json`:

```
{
    "title": "this is title",
    "Description": " Fendi is an Italian luxury labelarin. ",
    "url": "https:/~"
}

{
    "title": " - Furrocious Elegant Style",
    "Description": " the Italian luxare vast. ",
    "url": "https://www.s"
}

{
    "title": "Rome, Fountains and Fendi Sunglasses",
    "Description": " Fendi started off as a store. ",
    "url": "https://www.~"
}

{
    "title": "Tipsnglasses",
    "Description": "Whether irregular orn season.",
    "url": "https://www.sooic"
}
```

and this is my python code:

```
import json

with open('me.json', 'r') as obj:
    a = obj.read()
    for i in a:
        medict = dict(i)
```

I don't know why it is not working, what is wrong with it.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: `import json` and `with open('me.json') as infile: L = json.load(infile)`

Comment: to convert a json file into python dict you should use json.load(obj). what's the error that you receive ??

Comment: The input file isn't proper json. I would recommend surrounding the input with [ ] so it can be read easily with `json.loads()`

Comment: The [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50384432/1322401) on the marked duplicate isn't the accepted one.  It allows you to parse the json without editing it first.

Comment: @tchatow: Surrounding with `[ ]` isn't enough.  Commas would be needed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `json.loads`.
But, You have to change the data in file as json format first. Please use the following data.
I added `[`, `]` and `,`.

```
[{
    "title": "this is title",
    "Description": " Fendi is an Italian luxury labelarin. ",
    "url": "https:/~"
}
,
{
    "title": " - Furrocious Elegant Style",
    "Description": " the Italian luxare vast. ",
    "url": "https://www.s"
}
,
{
    "title": "Rome, Fountains and Fendi Sunglasses",
    "Description": " Fendi started off as a store. ",
    "url": "https://www.~"
}
,
{
    "title": "Tipsnglasses",
    "Description": "Whether irregular orn season.",
    "url": "https://www.sooic"
}]
```

And, Refer the following code:

```
import json

with open('me.json', 'r') as obj:
    a = obj.read()
    medict = json.loads(a)
    print (medict)
```

The result is :

```
[{'title': 'this is title', 'Description': ' Fendi is an Italian luxury labelarin. ', 'url': 'https:/~'}, {'title': ' - Furrocious Elegant Style', 'Description': ' the Italian luxare vast. ', 'url': 'https://www.s'}, {'title': 'Rome, Fountains and Fendi Sunglasses', 'Description': ' Fendi started off as a store. ', 'url': 'https://www.~'}, {'title': 'Tipsnglasses', 'Description': 'Whether irregular orn season.', 'url': 'https://www.sooic'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `re` module to find JSON objects in the input file (which isn't strictly in [JSON format](http://json.org)) as it is shown in your question (i.e. no need to modify it):

```
import ast
import json
from pprint import pprint
import re

with open('me.json', 'r') as obj:
    data = obj.read()
    matches = re.findall(r'({.+?})', data,  re.DOTALL)
    result = [json.loads(m) for m in matches]

pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'Description': ' Fendi is an Italian luxury labelarin. ',
  'title': 'this is title',
  'url': 'https:/~'},
 {'Description': ' the Italian luxare vast. ',
  'title': ' - Furrocious Elegant Style',
  'url': 'https://www.s'},
 {'Description': ' Fendi started off as a store. ',
  'title': 'Rome, Fountains and Fendi Sunglasses',
  'url': 'https://www.~'},
 {'Description': 'Whether irregular orn season.',
  'title': 'Tipsnglasses',
  'url': 'https://www.sooic'}]
```