# Why does json.load not read this?

Tags: python, json, syntax-error

`json` can't read more than 1 dictionary.

Code:

```
with open('jsonfile.json', 'r') as a:
    o = json.load(a)
    print(o)
```

jsonfile.json:

```
{
    "1234567899": {
        "username": "1",
        "password": "1",
        "email": "example@example.com"
    }
},
{
    "9987654321": {
        "username": "2",
        "password": "2",
        "email": "example@example.com"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
File "unknown", line 8

    {
    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why does the `,` not work to separate the json dictionaries?

Comment: I think this is not valid JSON... It should be enclosed in `[ ]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python)

Comment: This is not a valid json. JSON is a single element - here you two elements, separated by a comma. Add `[` and `]` to make it a list or remove the middle `},{` (leave only a comma) to make it a big dictionary.

Comment: Not a dupe, the other question does not have the `,` separating objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is causing an error because it is an invalid JSON. One solution is to have one overall dictionary:

```
{
    "1234567899": {
        "username": "1",
        "password": "1",
        "email": "example@example.com"
    },
    "9987654321": {
        "username": "2",
        "password": "2",
        "email": "example@example.com"
    }
}
```

Another is to have a list containing your various dictionaries:

```
[{
    "1234567899": {
        "username": "1",
        "password": "1",
        "email": "example@example.com"
    }
},
{
    "9987654321": {
        "username": "2",
        "password": "2",
        "email": "example@example.com"
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma *does* separate the objects, but `json.load` expects the contents of the file to be a *single* JSON value, not a comma-separate series of values.

The simplest fix is to wrap the contents in brackets first to produce a single JSON array.

```
import json
from itertools import chain


with open('jsonfile.json', 'r') as a:
    contents = chain(['['], a, [']'])
    o = json.loads(''.join(contents))
    print(o)
```

Comment: I think this has potential to halt your system if the file is bigger than available RAM (even 1/4 of available RAM if it contains unicode). Also, why not just `"[" + a + "]"`?