# JSON files parsing error while trying to print certain values using Python (json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 20))

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am new to Python, and I want to convert a JSON file and print it to the console. When I try to print the whole JSON it is throwing

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 20)

My code:

```
import json

with open('venv/Vt.json', 'r') as json_file:
    parsed_json = json.load(json_file)
for idd in parsed_json:
    print(idd['t_id'])
```

My JSON file:

```
{"index":{"_id":0}}
{"t_id":0,"timestamp":"2016-06-01T09:23:39Z","stat":"571","mod":"M02"}
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"t_id":0,"timestamp":"2016-06-01T09:23:39Z","stat":"571","mod":"M02"}
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. `json.load` expects a single object. You could wrap your code in `[ ... ]` to make it a list (include commas after each object). Or you could loop through the lines in your file and call `json.loads()` on each one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python)

Comment: But I have 1000 of json file of same type. How do I take specific values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you wait for a better answer, this code (while not great) solves your issue:

```
with open('venv/Vt.json', 'r') as json_file:
    try:
        t_ids = [json.loads(line)['t_id'] for line in json_file.readlines()]
        print(t_ids)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines' I am getting this error.

Comment: Ah ye my bad, I quickly wrote it down as str code to troubleshoot rather than an open file object. I've fixed it

Comment: Cool... Thank You. Just I had tried like this, lines = [re.sub("[\[\{\]]*", "", one_object.rstrip()) for one_object in json_as_string.readlines()]

json_as_list = "".join(lines).split('}')

Both worked but your's was very simple and clean. Thank's for the support