# Error reading big json file due to json.load

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, nltk

I have a problem reading big json file. JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 884 (char 883). 
[image]

The files test2.json is here: https://github.com/SilverYar/TransportDataMiner

The error is due to these lines of line code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.snowball import RussianStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk, string, json

with open('C:\\Creme\\token\\test2.json') as fin:
    text = json.load(fin)
```

I don’t understand how to fix it. Help me fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python)

Comment: Error reading large json file. The answers did not help me.

Comment: The size of the file is not relevant here. The file is not valid JSON. It's a bunch of JSON objects concatenated together. See the dupe target for some ways to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

The content of your json file does not seem to be valid, there are multiple objects but not separated by ",".

For example, a valid json object should be:

```
[{"title":"some text", "subtitle": "some text"},
 {"title":"some text", "subtitle": "some text"},
{"title":"some text", "subtitle": "some text"}]
```

A simple hack to read it will be to read in the file and format the string into correct json formats:

```
with open('test2.json', 'r') as fin:
    text = fin.read()
    formated_text = text.replace('}{', '},{')
    json_data = json.loads(f'[{formated_text}]')

print(len(json_data))
# 11772
```

Comment: @Yaroslav You're welcome, please accept the answer if it's correct :)