# Parse and grep a log file that has JSON format entries

Tags: python, json

I want to parse a log from pilight. It has multiple JSON entries, mostly datetime entries, it is not a single JSON string. So, when I use `json.load(f)` I get an error

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 12 column 1 (char 171)

Below is the example file. How would I parse such a file?

What I want to do is to suppress the complete JSON entries that have `"protocol": "datetime"` but keep the first of them after a complete JSON entry that is not datetime.

Thus, I would get a new reduced logfile that has the "messages" followed by a single "datetime" section. In the example that file would contain only the first 2 JSON entries.

```
{
    "message": {
        "id": 31,
        "unit": 15,
        "state": "down"
    },
    "origin": "receiver",
    "protocol": "arctech_screen_old",
    "uuid": "0000-b8-27-eb-e85eff",
    "repeats": 1
}
{
    "origin": "receiver",
    "protocol": "datetime",
    "message": {
        "longitude": 9.000000,
        "latitude": 44.633000,
        "year": 2020,
        "month": 6,
        "day": 5,
        "weekday": 6,
        "hour": 12,
        "minute": 41,
        "second": 30,
        "dst": 1
    },
    "uuid": "0000-b8-27-eb-e85eff"
}
{
    "origin": "receiver",
    "protocol": "datetime",
    "message": {
        "longitude": 9.000000,
        "latitude": 44.633000,
        "year": 2020,
        "month": 6,
        "day": 5,
        "weekday": 6,
        "hour": 12,
        "minute": 41,
        "second": 31,
        "dst": 1
    },
    "uuid": "0000-b8-27-eb-e85eff"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of your file is not a proper json. You need to separate objects with `,` and put everything in list like that`[{...}, {...}, ... ]`.

Here is example code:

```py
# assuming we have loaded your file to a str variable 

file_content = '''
{
    "message": {
        "id": 31,
        "unit": 15,
        "state": "down"
    },
    "origin": "receiver",
    "protocol": "arctech_screen_old",
    "uuid": "0000-b8-27-eb-e85eff",
    "repeats": 1
}
{
    "origin": "receiver",
    "protocol": "datetime",
    "message": {
        "longitude": 9.000000,
        "latitude": 44.633000,
        "year": 2020,
        "month": 6,
        "day": 5,
        "weekday": 6,
        "hour": 12,
        "minute": 41,
        "second": 30,
        "dst": 1
    },
    "uuid": "0000-b8-27-eb-e85eff"
}
{
    "origin": "receiver",
    "protocol": "datetime",
    "message": {
        "longitude": 9.000000,
        "latitude": 44.633000,
        "year": 2020,
        "month": 6,
        "day": 5,
        "weekday": 6,
        "hour": 12,
        "minute": 41,
        "second": 31,
        "dst": 1
    },
    "uuid": "0000-b8-27-eb-e85eff"
}
'''
```

Changing to a proper json would look like:

```py
import json
import re

proper_json_string = '[\n'+re.sub(r'}\n{', r'},\n{', file_content)+'\n]'
data = json.loads(proper_json_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [How to extract multiple JSON objects from one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/how-to-extract-multiple-json-objects-from-one-file/50384432#50384432) 
Easiest is to add `[` and `]` at the start and end of file respectively, and `,` between any single json object.

Once loaded, and you have a list of 'json' objects, you can do the following to filter them:

```
filtered_jsons = [single_json for single_json in all_jsons if single_json.get('protocol') != "datetime"]
```