# How to read multiple lists of JSON data from one file into Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have a script that collects JSON data from Twitter's API. This script collects data and parses it with `jq` every minute. This data gets collected into a single file that ends up looking like the following:

```
[
  {"text": "Tweet 01",
   "id": "001"
  },
  {"text": "Tweet 02",
   "id": "002"
  },
  {"text": "Tweet 03",
   "id": "003"
  }
]
[
  {"text": "Tweet 04",
   "id": "004"
  },
  {"text": "Tweet 05",
   "id": "005"
  },
  {"text": "Tweet 06",
   "id": "006"
  },
  {"text": "Tweet 07",
   "id": "007"
  },
  {"text": "Tweet 08",
   "id": "008"
  }
]
[
  {"text": "Tweet 09",
   "id": "009"
  },
  {"text": "Tweet 10",
   "id": "010"
  }
]
```

I've previously had a single list of JSON data per file, and Pandas easily can work with one list in a file. But how can I efficiently iterate over these multiple lists, that are NOT comma-separated and are NOT of necessarily the same length?

My ultimate goal is to aggregate ALL the JSON data from this one file and convert it to a CSV file, where each column is a key in the JSON data. It should end up looking like:

```
text, id
Tweet 01, 001
Tweet 02, 002
Tweet 03, 003
Tweet 04, 004
Tweet 05, 005
Tweet 06, 006
Tweet 07, 007
Tweet 08, 008
Tweet 09, 009
Tweet 10, 010
```

If I were to try reading the file anyway, the following occurs:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_json("sample.json")
>>> df.head()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lists.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_json("sample.json")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 608, in read_json
    result = json_reader.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 731, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 753, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 857, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 1089, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Trailing data
```

Comment: Possible solutions here using `JSONDecoder.raw_decode`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/how-to-extract-multiple-json-objects-from-one-file/27907893#27907893. JSON is not a good format for appending data like this unless you don't pretty print and make each json a single line. You could also add your own decorations like "===============" between records so you can split the file before getting the json. But really, choose a  better format. A simple CSV would work well here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Trenton McKinney said, you need to clean the data. So you could use [`f.read()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp) to get the file as a string, then [`str.replace()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/) to replace the `']\n['` with `','`, because `']\n['` it's causing the error, and finally
you could try with [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html):

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data=f.read()
data=data.replace(']\n[',',')

df=pd.read_json(data)
```

Output:

```
df
0  Tweet 01   1
1  Tweet 02   2
2  Tweet 03   3
3  Tweet 04   4
4  Tweet 05   5
5  Tweet 06   6
6  Tweet 07   7
7  Tweet 08   8
8  Tweet 09   9
9  Tweet 10  10
```

Answer (score 1):

- The file contents need to be converted to a standard list, by reading the file in, and converting the individual lists into a single list.
- [`.readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) reads each row of the file in as a list of strings

  - Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to iterate through each row, to remove whitespace and newlines at the front and tail of the string, using [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) combines items in a list into a single string.
- [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to replace `']['` with `','`.
- Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the string back to an list.

```py
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

# open and clean the contents of the file
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    data = literal_eval(''.join([row.strip() for row in f.readlines()]).replace('][', ','))

# print(data)
[{'text': 'Tweet 01', 'id': '001'},
 {'text': 'Tweet 02', 'id': '002'},
 {'text': 'Tweet 03', 'id': '003'},
 {'text': 'Tweet 04', 'id': '004'},
 {'text': 'Tweet 05', 'id': '005'},
 {'text': 'Tweet 06', 'id': '006'},
 {'text': 'Tweet 07', 'id': '007'},
 {'text': 'Tweet 08', 'id': '008'},
 {'text': 'Tweet 09', 'id': '009'},
 {'text': 'Tweet 10', 'id': '010'}]

# load into pandas
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# display(df)
       text   id
0  Tweet 01  001
1  Tweet 02  002
2  Tweet 03  003
3  Tweet 04  004
4  Tweet 05  005
5  Tweet 06  006
6  Tweet 07  007
7  Tweet 08  008
8  Tweet 09  009
9  Tweet 10  010
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the original json file fits in memory, you can use `raw_decoder` to pull the json lists out, one at a time. `raw_decoder` returns the length of data consumed in the parse and you can trim the string and continue til no data remains.

```
import csv
import json
with open('data.json') as f:
    rawdata = f.read()

decoder = json.JSONDecoder().raw_decode

with open('data.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=["id", "text"])
    while rawdata:
        data, idx = decoder(rawdata)
        writer.writerows(data)
        rawdata = rawdata[idx:].lstrip()

print(open('data.csv').read())
```