# Optimal way to parse Twitter JSON objects from one file/multiple files into python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have the Twitter dataset (multiple JSON files), but let's start from one file. I have to parse JSON objects to python but `json.loads()` only parse one object. A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/how-to-extract-multiple-json-objects-from-one-file) but solutions are not working or good enough.

1- I can not convert JSON objects into the list as it is not efficient and I have too much data. Also proposed solutions are based on "\n" while my Twitter data objects end like `}{` there is no `newline` and I can not add manually. (Twitter objects are also  not line by line)

2- The second solution is `JSONStream` and there is not much available about it on [official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/jsonstream/).

3- Is there any other efficient way? One I have in consideration is using `MongoDB`. but I never worked on `MongoDB`. so I don't know if this is possible with this or not.

below picture shows the length of tweet object and `}{`

[image]

```
with open('sampledata.json','r',encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    #for i in json_file:
     while(True):
        dataobj = json.load(json_file)
        print(dataobj)
print("Printing each JSON Decoded Object")
```

Error:
As there are 287 lines for one object.

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 287 column 2 (char 10528)
```

Comment: you don't need the `while` loop

Comment: where is the json file coming from? `}{` is invalid json...

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop used while reading the json file is not needed
You can use this to read a json file:

```py
def read_json(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

my_data = read_json('sampledata.json')
```